# How to filter the a column with isoweek values in BigQuery in StandardSQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table where I want to filter only the last 4 weeks - challenge: the date range of the underlying table must be from 2018 - 2021 so that all other columns can be filled. Filtering the date did not work for me, because then I wouldn't get data for the columns of the previous year.

How can I filter the table so that I always get the last 4 weeks from today but also have the data of all other columns?

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| isoweek | sessions_2021 | sessions_2020 | sessions_2019 | sessions_2018 |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| 44      |        534260 |        156450 |        476604 |        539819 |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| 45      |        514197 |        133285 |        481228 |        491133 |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| 46      |        487541 |        122930 |        448876 |        485281 |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| 47      |        502791 |        169920 |        267869 |        491630 |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| 48      |        430129 |        144058 |          null |        459051 |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| 49      |        410885 |        127426 |          null |        468970 |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| 50      |        183323 |        147254 |          null |        438814 |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| 51      |          null |        122491 |          null |        455786 |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| 52      |          null |         70972 |          null |        478501 |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
| 53      |          null |          null |         52712 |          null |  |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--+
```

Comment: Not clear (at least for me) what exactly the input data and what is expected output? check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question please so we can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is the example table you have above you can try the following:

```
with sample_data as (
    select isoweek from unnest(generate_array(1,52,1)) as isoweek
)

select isoweek
from sample_data
where isoweek between extract(isoweek from date_sub(current_date(),INTERVAL 4 WEEK)) 
    and extract(isoweek from current_date());
```